# Bootstrap 4 six boxes in the same row (responsive)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make six boxes on the same line with spacing between them?

I've tried everything, but to get the margin between them I had to use very negative margins and the design was not responsive :(

I leave here an example of what I want

[image]

Comment: Pretty easy with [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#how-it-works): [example](https://jsfiddle.net/71exz5sf/)

Comment: Can you add what are those that you tried? This can be easily done by **Bootstrap**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using bootstrap grid structure:

```css
.content {
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added wrong `bootstrap 4` link. Will you please replace it with this one? https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: Ya ,sure. Added

Comment: You forget to include `rel="stylesheet"`. Allow me to edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use col and mr (margin-right) like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col mr-3">
      1 of 6
    </div>
    <div class="col mr-3">
      2 of 6
    </div>
    <div class="col mr-3">
      3 of 6
    </div>
    <div class="col mr-3">
      4 of 6
    </div>
    <div class="col mr-3">
      5 of 6
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      6 of 6
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col mr-3">
      1 of 6
    </div>
    <div class="col mr-3">
      2 of 6
    </div>
    <div class="col mr-3">
      3 of 6
    </div>
    <div class="col mr-3">
      4 of 6
    </div>
    <div class="col mr-3">
      5 of 6
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      6 of 6
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8g2L5036/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Jsfiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/cm2kqstb/18/). My suggession is not to use bootstrap `.row` and `.col` classes if it is not a layout change. According to the problem explained above, it is a some kind of items view, so I recommend here to use pure `flex` css styles to arrange those boxes.

```css
.box-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: calc(16.66% - 10px);
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 85px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">01</div>
        <div class="box">02</div>
        <div class="box">03</div>
        <div class="box">04</div>
        <div class="box">05</div>
        <div class="box">06</div>

        <div class="box">01</div>
        <div class="box">02</div>
        <div class="box">03</div>
        <div class="box">04</div>
        <div class="box">05</div>
        <div class="box">06</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: If OP is not using bootstrap already for other things in the project, I agree, much leaner approach for just that one task

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1-1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1-2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1-3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1-4
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1-5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1-6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      2-1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2-2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2-3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2-4
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2-5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2-6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```